# I am using Maven in Eclipse and it shows an error message saying that I may be using a JRE. However, I am using a JDK. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to run a "maven test" and I get this error in the console:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project gpdb-dispomap: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

However, when I run a "clean install" it works and I don't get this message.
How can I resolve this?

This is my JDK settings:
[image]

Comment: As the output says use a JDK for JAVA_HOME instead of JRE ?...

Comment: I am using a JDK please see the edit.

Comment: Not for Maven. You are using that in Eclipse.......

Comment: Maven in eclipse makes use of the jdk. It works fine if I do clean install

Comment: As I said you have to set JAVA_HOME to run Maven on the console. No relationship to Eclipse.

Comment: Where do you have run the `clean install` ? ???

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/EBMeZFZ) is where the clean install is ran

Comment: @Justin The JRE or JDK to run Maven can be chosen in the run configuration in the _JRE_ tab.

Comment: @khmarbaise The question is how to do this in Eclipse, not on the command line. There is no reason to switch to the command line here.

Comment: Then the question why would you like to run "mvn clean install" ? And not running from IDE only? I'm completely confused ... what are you really like to achieve? Building your project correctly from command line or working in your IDE?

Comment: @khmarbaise The command line command `mvn` is not mentioned here at all.